# Typolink to index Pages on solr

Tags: solr, typo3, typo3-9.x

I setup a TYPO3 v.9 website with solr.

And for some reason, the Pages indexer not working. So I used the custom TS configuration bellow, to work around and to force Pages indexing. With this custom TS, pages was indexed, BUT the links to a Page from the "Search results" is not working.

This is my custom TS :

```
#TS added to force page indexing              
plugin.tx_solr.index.queue {
snar_pages = 1
snar_pages {
    table = pages
    fields {
        title = title
        content = SOLR_CONTENT
        content {
            cObject = COA
            cObject {
                10 = TEXT
                10 {
                    field = bodytext
                    noTrimWrap = || |
                }
            }
        }
        url = CASE
        url {
            key.field = type

            # Internal
            1 = TEXT
            1 {
                if.isTrue.field = internalurl
                typolink.parameter.field = internalurl
                typolink.useCacheHash = 1
                typolink.returnLast = url
            }

            # External
            2 = TEXT
            2 {
                if.isTrue.field = externalurl
                field = externalurl
            }
            default = TEXT
            default {
                typolink.parameter = {link}
                typolink.additionalParams >
                typolink.useCacheHash = 1
                typolink.returnLast = url
            }
        }
}
```

}

is there an error in my TS that prevents the links to the pages from working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing my TS as follows, and this fixed my problem :

```
url = CASE
url {
   key.field = doktype
   default = TEXT
   default {
       field = title
       typolink.parameter.field = uid
       typolink.returnLast = url
}
```

PS : pages need to be re-indexed for good results.

Answer (score 0):

hmm i think you missed something to setup too for indexing pages. The DataFrontendHelper
see the [docs](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/solr/stable/Configuration/Reference/TxSolrIndex.html#queue-pages-indexer-frontenddatahelper-scheme)

edited:

```js
plugin.tx_solr {
    index {

        queue {
            pages {
                indexer {
                    frontendDataHelper {
                        host    = {$plugin.tx_solr.indexer.frontendDataHandler.host}
                        scheme  = {$plugin.tx_solr.indexer.frontendDataHandler.scheme}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not the same as the follwing ? 
`plugin.tx_solr.solr.port = 89xx

plugin.tx_solr.solr.useCurlHttpTransport = 0

plugin.tx_solr.solr.host = 192.xxx.xxx.xxx

plugin.tx_solr.solr.path = /solr/corename/

plugin.tx_solr.solr.path = /solr/corename/`

Comment: no it is not had the same issue, this is the solr-server configuration, now you need to define the FrontendURL and Schema (http or https) which need to be parsed by typo3-solr extension before sending to be indexed by solr-server.